# Bootstrap carousel buttons visible on the footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been building a website using bootstraps scrollspy. So far so good, except that carousel buttons are appearing over my footer

[image: Image here]

Here is the footer css:

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: you could try setting the z index of the buttons lower than the z-index of the footer itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @zack6849 said if you add the z-index property to the .footer css it should resolve your issue provided you spec a value higher than that of your slider. You should inspect the element and see what the current z-indexes are, or just use a real high value for your footer like z-index:10000;

you can read more about [z-index here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Thanks for this. It was really helpful.